# SonarQube services are active but I can't access the Web page on my Ubuntu 22.04 local machine

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube

[image]

[image: 1]

JDK version 11

I followed all the steps for installing sonarqube and update my java version from 8 to 11 also

SonarQube service are active but I can't access the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run SonarQube as root, as mentioned here https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/configure-and-operate-a-server/operating-the-server/#running-sonarqube-as-service-linux-systemd:

> On a Unix system using SystemD, you can install SonarQube as a service. You cannot run SonarQube as root in Unix systems. Ideally, you will have created a new account dedicated to the purpose of running SonarQube.

So you need a different (ideally, dedicated) user to run SonarQube. And that user should have all permissions (777) on the SonarQube directory (and all directories/files inside of it). The error you're getting appears to be a case of the user not having the necessary file permissions recursively.